# Get FB public posts by country

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

is it possible to get all FB public posts from a location(city/country)? I don't want any of the user's info , I am solely interested in the posts.

Comment: What about using locale parameters?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this by using the [Public Feed API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/).

The Public Feed API provides a stream of user status updates and page status updates as they are posted to Facebook. But, the stream only includes basic data about the given post. However, you can user [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) to request additional data, like place (*country*) for a particular post and sort them out based on their country.

NOTE: Access to the Public Feed API is restricted to a limited set of media publishers and usage requires prior approval by Facebook. You cannot use the API without the approval.

Comment: Public Feed API is a restricted API.Ryt?
"Access to the Public Feed API is restricted to a limited set of media publishers and usage requires prior approval by Facebook. You cannot apply to use the API at this time."

Comment: Of course. You require a prior approval from Facebook in order to use that. Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Any idea on how to get approval for it/?

Comment: Not sure. But, I think we can do that by contacting a Facebook representative either by phone of using a [contact form](https://www.facebook.com/business/contactus).